# Почему не дает оставить положенные 40 голосов за день?

Tags: поддержка, голоса-за

Я вот получил 36 голосов за день и больше не могу голосовать. Перечитал алгоритм, правила, но все равно ничего не понял. Объясните, как нужно отдавать голоса, чтобы получить максимум?

Answer (score 8):

в справке сказано:

> В течение 24 часов вы можете проголосовать 30 раз. 10 дополнительных голосов выделяются только на вопросы.

поэтому попробуйте поставить голоса «за» на вопросы